# To get JSON object as response in djangorestapi

Tags: python, json, api, django-rest-framework, backend

After using POST method for the following object, I want to return the id of created object in JSON format. I tried converting a python dict to json format it didn't work.

```
{
        "name": "m15",
        "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/fb/bd/6ffbbd3938131ddd7f07948966772435.jpg",
        "caption": "c15"
}
```

Expected output

```
{
'id':15
}
```

Following is my views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import Meme
from .serializers import MemeSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class ListMeme(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        memes = Meme.objects.all()
        serializer = MemeSerializer(memes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MemeSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class DetailMeme(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Meme.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemeSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simple way in above case would be override the create method of `MemeSerializer`.

In create method of `MemeSerializer`

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    """
    Overriding the create method to return
    only id of created instance
    """
    meme: Meme = Meme.objects.create(**validaed_data)
    return {id: meme.id}
```

Another way to approach this problem would be to create another model serializer  with all other fields as `read_only` and `id` as only `write_only` field. This, in turn, can be done using two different ways

```
# method 1

class CreateMemeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   name: str = serializers.CharField(max_length=..., read_only)
   ...
   id: int = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

   class Meta:
      model = Meme

# method 2
class CreateMemeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
      model = Meme
      ...
      extra_kwags = {
         "name": {"read_only": True},
         ...
         "id": {"write_only": True},
      }

# and use this in your view
      ...
      def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CreateMemeSerializer(data=request.data)
      ...
```

On side note, you can also use viewsets in your case.